# What is wrong with this if Get-ChildItem statement in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'm having trouble getting the following PowerShell statement to work. The objective is to get a list of folders which are in the `..\archive` folder sorted by oldest to youngest.

I would like to copy the number of folders which amount to or less than `$ClosedJobssize` from the `..\Archive` to the `..\movetotape` folder. This is so the size of the ..\Archive folder never changes on the hard drive.

```
get-childitem -path "\\srv02\d$\Prepress\Archive" | sort-object -property

@{Expression={$_.CreationTime};Ascending=$false} | % { if (((get-childitem -path

"\\srv02\d$\prepress\archive" -recurse -force | measure-object -Property Length -Sum).Sum + $_.Length)

-lt $closedjobssize ) { move-item -destination "\\srv02\d$\prepress\archive\MoveToTape\" }}
```

What might I be doing wrong? I don't get any errors. It just sits and hangs when I execute it.

Comment: `(get-childitem -path "\\srv02\d$\prepress\archive" -recurse -force | measure-object -Property Length -Sum).Sum` will get you the total size, including subfolders of all files in the archive directory.  I don't understand what you're trying to achieve by adding the current pipeline object's length to that for the comparison.  It's also expensive, and you're doing it for every object piped to it...  

Then, `move-item -destination "\\srv02\d$\prepress\archive\MoveToTape\"` doesn't specify a source, and thus does nothing (likely would prompt you for a source if the script ever got that far).

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It's a long one-liner (remove `-whatIf` to perform the move):

```
dir "\\srv02\d$\Prepress\Archive" | sort CreationTime -desc | where { $_.psiscontainer -AND (dir $_.fullname -recurse -force | measure-object -Property Length -Sum).Sum -lt $closedjobssize} | Move-Item -dest "\\srv02\d$\prepress\archive\MoveToTape\" -whatIf
```

Comment: the one liner didn't work for me.  It just copied everything into the movetotape folder

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand. But I think you want to move folders in `\archive` to `\archive\movetotape` to fill up `\movetotape` until it is `$ClosedJobsSize` or less in size.  Right?

A couple of things: You are adding up the size of everything in `\archive`, so the result of your comparison will never change. Second, one of the folders checked is `MoveToTape` itself, which could cause you to move it into itself (this should give an exception).

Given that, I think this code will work, but I haven't tested it.

```
## Get all the directories in \arcive that need to be moved
$Directories = Get-ChildItem "\\srv02\d$\Prepress\Archive" |
    Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.Name -ne "MoveToTape")} | Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending
foreach ($Directory in $Directories)
{
    $SumOfMoveToTape = (Get-ChildItem "\\srv02\d$\prepress\archive\MoveToTape\" -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum
    $SumOfItem = (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum
    if(($SumOfMoveToTape + $SumOfItem) -lt $ClosedJobsSize)
    {
        ## If we can fit on MoveToTape, then move this directory
        Move-Item -Destination "\\srv02\d$\prepress\archive\MoveToTape\"
    }
    ## If you want to keep folders in order (and not try to squeze whatever onto the tape
    ## then put an 'else {break}' here
}
```

Comment: The objective is to shift files from one folder to another of the same size.  So if 1 gig of data came from the closedjobs folder and placed into the archive, then 1 gb of the oldest files should come out of the archive to go into the movetotape folder. thanks!

Comment: Then I think my code will do that.  It will fill up \movetotape with folders from \archive until \movetotape full with $ClosedJobsSize amount of data (or it runs out of stuff to move).  Give it a test and let me know if it is what you need.

Comment: I'm not seeing where does it calculate $closedJobsSize?  is there a missing line?

Comment: You did not specify how it is calculated, so I assume that it is statically defined, or you figure it out somehow.